# Using SKNode objects for keys in NSDictionary? (Compare issue)

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

Objective-C

Consider this code:

```
SKNode *n1 = [SKNode new];
SKNode *n2 = [SKNode new];

NSMutableDictionary *d = [NSMutableDictionary new];

[d setObject:@"A" forKey:n1];
[d setObject:@"B" forKey:n2];


if ([d objectForKey:n1]) {
    NSLog(@"true");
}
```

I'm using SKNode as keys in NSDictionary.  I need to test if a given SKNode exists as a Key.  The common approaches for testing don't seem to work, as above the result will not return (or print) "true".  Neither will the following code:

```
if ([d allKeys] containsObject:n1]) {
    NSLog(@"true");
}
```

If I make the keys strings; i.e @"key1", @"key2", "true" is printed.

Is it possible to test in this manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(It occurred to me that what I wrote as a comment was actually the answer to the question.)

NSDictionary copies its keys (using `-copy` from the NSCopying protocol). SKNode conforms to NSCopying, but copying a node returns a new node that isn't equal to the old one:

```
SKNode *a = [SKNode new];
SKNode *b = [a copy];

[a isEqual:b];  // NO
```

```
let a = SKNode()
let b = a.copy() as! SKNode

a == b  // false
```

So it's not safe to use SKNodes as keys in a dictionary. As for workarounds: you could perhaps use the node's `name` as a key (if your nodes' names are unique). You could also use NSMapTable, which doesn't copy its keys.

Comment: I just did the same experiment (in objective c) but hesitated to answer because I don't have an explanation of the result.  Shouldn't it be the case generally that `[[object copy] isEqual:object] == YES` ? That's why conforming to NSCopying is sufficient for dictionary keys.

Comment: It would make intuitive sense if that were true, and I think it is true in most cases, but I don't see it as even an informal requirement of NSCopying. It appears SKNode chooses to implement `copy()` to allow you to clone a node, and with that goal in mind it makes sense that the new node isn't equal to the old one.

Comment: Here's a good article I just found discussing the diffs / advantages of using NSDict vs NSMapTable.  http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/07/nsmaptable-more-than-nsdictionary-for.html

Comment: Yes, NSMapTable has a bunch of other features which can be really useful. For a case like this, though, all you need is `strongToStrongObjectsMapTable`, and you basically get the same behavior as NSMutableDictionary except for the key-copying.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work. So something is wrong here, possibly with the implementation of the hashcode and isEqual: method of SKNode.

Log the hash code of your two keys, check what isEqual: returns, log the dictionary and all the keys, and check for anything unexpected.

PS. It turns jtbandes answer is *exactly* the right one. Of course following my advice and logging everything you would have found that the keys in allKeys are not what's expected, with a fighting chance of figuring out the answer.

So if you have a class with trivial hashcode and isEqual, just taking the pointer as hashcode and comparing pointers for isEqual, then *either* you have a class where copy creates a new object and a dictionary won't work, or you have a class where copy just returns the original object and it works fine.

Comment: `copy` creating a new object is not disqualifying for using the object as a dictionary key.  Doing an alloc in copy is typical, and it's typical and desirable that the new and the original objects produce colliding hashes and together answer isEqual == true.